# Tennessee Honey Jack Daniels substitution

Tags: substitutions

What can be substituted for Tennessee Honey Jack Daniels in a recipe, I don't have any in my home.  I have not been able to try anything yet.

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you post the recipe you are making and what effect you want you'll get much better answers, as it is your question is likely to be closed as being unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Do you have regular Jack Daniels, and some honey?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The flavored varieties of Jack Daniels (and most other brands, really) are nothing more than the same base whiskey, cut with additives including neutral spirits, sugar, and water.  You can very easily add those last at home.

Make a honey syrup by combining honey and boiling water in equal amounts by volume in a heat-proof container; stir this until combined, allow to cool, and store in a sealed container in the refrigerator. This is both easier to mix with alcohol (just [ask a bartender](http://imbibemagazine.com/honey-syrup-recipe/)) and will provide some dilution.

[Honey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey#Nutrition_and_composition) has about 17 grams of sugar per tablespoon (which equals 1/2 oz) and we've diluted it by half (so we now have the same sugar content of 17 grams per 1 oz). There's no exact information available for Tennessee Honey, but [one estimate](http://www.drinkspirits.com/other/nutritional-information-liquor-labels/) pegs the sugar content at about 6 grams in a 1.5 oz serving (which we'll convert to 4 grams per 1 oz). Many of these commercial liqueurs also include [other additives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propylene_glycol) which add a sweet taste and mouthfeel, so we'll err on the side of sweetness.  A little napkin math then tells us that 1 oz of honey syrup should be enough to sweeten 3 oz of standard Jack Daniel's (producing 4 total oz with 17 grams of sugar, for 4.25 g/oz). You can also use just about any other bourbon out there; Jack Daniel's tends to be a little sweeter in general, but we've accounted for that to a degree already.

You can ramp this up or down for any amount needed, using the same ratio of 1 part honey syrup to 3 parts Jack Daniel's (or bourbon).  And yes - that is a *lot* of sugar.